# Get value from form input to form action

Tags: html, forms

I have a HTMl form and I would like to put values from this form into the form action so I can redirect the user to the correct place after they submit the form.

I can get this working with 1 of the values, but I need 2 values.

Here is the working script:

```
function selectChangedAdgang(adgangValue) {
  alert("you choose: " + adgangValue);
  document.getElementById("documentForm").action = "/form.aspx?LINK=/intranet/dokumenter?adgang="+adgangValue; 
};
```

So I just need to have this script running "2 times", so I can input one more value from another input field.

Comment: Handle that in the ASP.NET, not in the client side JavaScript.

Comment: What is the aim of the code? To send something to the server to store or to return something to the user? and what is the HTML of the form. You likely want to look into AJAX

Comment: When the user uses the form they upload a file to a database. When they have filled out the form i would like to redirect them to where they put the file. For that i need 2 variables. The script is working fine with just 1 value, so I just need help to have two variables in the script :)

Comment: And why will  `document.getElementById("documentForm").action = "/form.aspx?LINK=/intranet/dokumenter?adgang="+adgangValue+"&othervalue="+othervalue` not work for you?

Comment: It might will but i am not quite sure how to do it. Sorry for these newbie questions. This is one of my HTML input fields:

<input name="name" id="id" value="All" type="checkbox" onchange="selectChangedAdgang(this.value)">All

I use the Onchange to put in in the script.
So if I have another field which should put in another value in the script how do i do this. For example. 

<input name="name" id="id" value="Group1" type="checkbox" onchange="selectChangedGroup(this.value)">Group1

That is the thing I need and I don't know how to get the value in the script, just the first one.

Comment: I understand how to put the value inside the action script at the end but cant get the second value inside the script and make it work :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass in multiple GET-paramters you do the following:

```
/form.aspx?LINK=/intranet/dokumenter?var1=value1&var2=value2
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. That part i understand, I might not have been clear in my question. I need help to get the value I have now and one more into the action. I actually just want to run this one more time with another value: "function selectChangedAdgang(adgangValue) {
    alert("you choose: " + adgangValue);"

Does that makes sence?

So i can do something like: function selectChangedNew(NewValue) {

at the same time as the other value, so I can pass both of them to the action

Comment: @user2239933 Why not pass in another value into the function and run another action? Does that work?

Comment: That is what I don't know how to do, can you please give me an example! :)